# How to match id's between data in Swift?

Tags: swift, swiftui

The screen representing user profile. I want to move to the profile of chosen friend (from 'friends' list). I suppose that I have to match between "id"s. This is how I've tried, but it doesn't work. How can I match "id"s?

```
// This didn't work
user: session.users.first(where: { $0.id == friend.id })
```

.

```
struct DetailView: View {
    var user: User
    var session: Session
    ...
    ...
    var body: some View {
    ...
        // ... user profile ...
        // Friends section
        ForEach(user.friends, id: \.self.id) { friend in

                    NavigationLink(destination: 
                        DetailView(user: session.users.first(where: { $0.id == friend.id }), 
                            session: session)) {

                        HStack {
                            Text(friend.name)
                        }
                    }
        }
     }
 }
```

this is the data organization.

```
class Session: ObservableObject {
    @Published var users = [User]()
}

struct User: Codable {
    var id: String
    var isActive: Bool
    var name: String
    var age: Int16
    var company, email, address, about: String
    var registered: Date
    var tags: [String]
    var friends: [Friend]
}

struct Friend: Codable {
    var id: String
    var name: String
}
```

**EDIT**

If there is a better way to match between "id"s. How social networks do this?

```
// added exclamation mark (!) and it worked out
session.users.first(where: { $0.id == friend.id })!
```

Comment: What exactly did not work?

Comment: user: session.users.first(where: { $0.id == friend.id })

Comment: Add ! this sign after user: session.users.first(where: { $0.id == friend.id })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you do this but your Details view does not have an optional User type and you have passed an optional user (Array.first gives you an optional object). So you need to handle this or add an exlemetion sign at the end. like this

```
session.users.first(where: { $0.id == friend.id })!
```

Comment: "why you do this..." - what did you mean, what should I do better?

Comment: I think to aspire answer suggestion (which is currently deleted). and make it optional inside the details page view.

Comment: like using this - (user: friend, session: session) ?

Comment: No. Inside the details view where you declare user variable,